# need help on how to either delay or run function in background (android App)

Tags: java, android

I have this code below that is in my main activity. Basicly whenever I click the button, it will first check if an alarm is set, if it is false it will go into a loop which reads the RSSI on a connected device until it is above a RSSI value. My question is how do i make this loop not crash my app, which it currently does. Also for some reason the mRSSI text field never gets populated with the RSSI value. Can someone please help me out. This is the last thing in my app i need to get done.

```
    public void onMonitorClick(final View view){
    if (isBLEEnabled()) {
        if (!isDeviceConnected()) {
            // do nothing
        } else if (isImmediateAlertOn == true) {
            showMonitor();
            DebugLogger.v(TAG, "app is high alert");
            isImmediateAlertOn = true;
        }
        else {
            DebugLogger.v(TAG, "app is no alert");
            hideMonitor();
            while(monitorStop != 1) 
            {

            ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssi();
            rssilevel = ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssiValue();
            if (rssilevel > -50 )   {
                DebugLogger.v(TAG, "greater then -50");
                monitorStop = 1;
            }
            mRSSI.setText("-" + String.valueOf(rssilevel) + "dB");
            isImmediateAlertOn = false;
            mFindMeButton.setEnabled(false);

            }
        }
    } else {
        showBLEDialog();
    }
}
```

edit redone code

```
public void onMonitorClick(final View view){
    if (isBLEEnabled()) {
        if (!isDeviceConnected()) {
                // do nothing
            } else if (monitorvis == 0) {
                showMonitor();              

        } else if (isImmediateAlertOn == true) {
            showMonitor();
            DebugLogger.v(TAG, "app is high alert");
            isImmediateAlertOn = true;
        }
        else {
            DebugLogger.v(TAG, "app is no alert");
            hideMonitor();
            monitorStop = 0; 
            do { run(); run2(); } while(monitorStop != 1);

        }
    } else {
        showBLEDialog();
    }
}


protected void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssi();
            rssilevel = ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssiValue();
            mRSSI.setText("-" + String.valueOf(rssilevel) + "dB");

        }
    });
}

protected void run2() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mRSSI.setText("-" + String.valueOf(rssilevel) + "dB");
            if (rssilevel < -60)
            {
                monitorStop = 1;
                showMonitor();
                ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).startImmediateAlert();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is  (IMHO) the easiest way to delay execution of a piece of code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do what you need to do
    }
}, MILISECONDS_BEFORE_EXECUTION);
```

Here, `MILISECONDS_BEFORE_EXECUTION` is a value (constant or variable) of the milliseconds you need to wait before executing the code. [Documentation of `Handler` in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: I feel like an idiot but how do i mix this with my code. I am not that experienced yet.

Comment: how would modify my edited code above to have a delay, also why doesnt mRSSI ever set the text other then when i press the button again?